# Unable to view pdf file in firestorage using flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, pdf, file-upload

I am unable to view the file, but I can confirm that the file has been uploaded, as the file size matches with the size I uploaded in the firestorage.

Not able to figure out the issue. I have attached the image and the code to upload and pick up file using flutter.Is there any other way to resolve?

[When I try to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChqMp.png)

But able to view the jpg files but why it's not working with pdf files.

Following code I executed to upload file to the firestore & also picking up the file.

```
Uint8List? selectedImageInBytes;
  List<Uint8List?> pickedImagesInBytes = [];
  List<String> imageUrls = [];
  List<String> fileUrls = [];
  int imageCounts = 0;
  List<String> selectedFiles = [];
  String _selectedFile = '';
  String _selectedFilePath = '';
  //to upload multiple files

  Future<String> _uploadMultipleFiles(String itemName) async {
     String imageUrl = '';
     try {
      for (var i = 0; i < imageCounts; i++) {
        firabase_storage.UploadTask uploadTask;

        firabase_storage.Reference ref = firabase_storage
            .FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref()
            .child('$_textField1')
            .child('/${selectedFiles[i]}');

        final metadata = firabase_storage.SettableMetadata(
            contentType: 'application/pdf,image/jpeg,image/jpg');

        //uploadTask = ref.putFile(File(file.path));
        uploadTask = ref.putData(pickedImagesInBytes[i]!, metadata);

        await uploadTask.whenComplete(() => null);
        imageUrl = await ref.getDownloadURL();
        setState(() {
           imageUrls.add(imageUrl);
        });
      }
    }catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return imageUrl;
  }

  
  //for uploading two files
  _selectFile(bool imageFrom) async {
    FilePickerResult? fileResult = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
        type: FileType.custom,
        allowedExtensions: [
          'jpg',
          'jpeg',
          'pdf'
        ],
        allowMultiple: true);

    if (fileResult != null) {
      PlatformFile file = fileResult.files.first;
      for (var file in fileResult.files) {
        if (file.size! > maxSizeInMB) {
          // File size exceeds the allowed limit
          print('File ${_selectedFile} exceeds the allowed size limit.');
          // You can display an error message to the user here if needed.
        } else {
          _selectedFile = fileResult.files.first.name;

          fileResult.files.forEach((element) {
            setState(() {
              pickedImagesInBytes.add(element.bytes);
              print(_selectedFile);
              //selectedImageInBytes = fileResult.files.first.bytes;
              selectedFiles.add(element.name);
              imageCounts += 1;
            });
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }

//calling of the fn:
await \_uploadMultipleFiles(\_selectedFile);
print('Uploaded Image URL ${imageUrls.length}');
print(imageUrls);
```

Comment: Try using putFile instead of putData, without metadata